# Automatic addition of columns to a data.frame in an R function

Tags: r, function, dataframe, subset

In function `foo` below, argument `long` accepts a **vector** of binary `T/F` input. Given the `data.frame` called `out` in my function, I want my function to add a column named `"long"` and populate it with `T`s for the `T` inputs and `F` for the `F` inputs from `"long"` argument. Also, I want my function to add a column named `"short"` and populate it with `F`s for the `T` inputs, and `T` for the `F` inputs from `"long"` argument.

Here is what I have tried with no success:

```
foo <- function(d, long){

nm <- if(!missing(long) & long) "long" else if(!missing(long) & !long) "short" # problematic

out <- data.frame(d)

if(!missing(long))out[nm] <- long  ## problematic

return(out)
}

 foo(d = 1:3, long = c(T, F,T))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```
foo <- function(d, long){
  data.frame(d, long = long, short = !long)
}

foo(d = 1:3, long = c(T, F,T))

#  d  long short
#1 1  TRUE FALSE
#2 2 FALSE  TRUE
#3 3  TRUE FALSE
```

Or if you want output as `"T"` and `"F"` only

```
foo <- function(d, long){
   out <- data.frame(d, long = long, short = !long)
   transform(out, long = substr(long, 1, 1), short = substr(short, 1, 1))
}

foo(d = 1:3, long = c(T, F,T))
#  d long short
#1 1    T     F
#2 2    F     T
#3 3    T     F
```